# git-cola not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, gui, git

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop. I installed git-cola. Installation is smooth with apt0get install git-cola. When I open git-cola from launcher, it ask to open/clone a repository. I gave the remote repository URL to clone. After sometime I am seeing just blank page. Even if i try to open the cloned repository it is not opening the local repository directory. I could see the files cloned successfully.

I tried this several times but no luck. I tried few alternatives git-gui, giggle, gitk but they are not satisfactory. Right now I have using terminal commands. any suggestion/options to get git-cola work on ubuntu 10.04.